# Why the selected radio button doesn't keep selected in a modal?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, radio-button, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have different modals that load a component in the same component. Each modal has a some radio buttons. When I open and select one, I open the modal again and the selected button is selected. However, I select the radio button in other modals and the previous radio button doesn't keep the selected. I'm using angular and bootstrap.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same instance of that component and not just instantiating a new one through different modals?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.